# Parse Dashboard can only be remotely accessed via HTTPS

Tags: ubuntu, parse-platform, https, digital-ocean, parse-server

I'm trying to deploy a Parse Server and Parse Dashboard on my DigitalOcean's server. I installed through docker-compose on this git:
https://github.com/yongjhih/docker-parse-server

When I access to it, http://rafael-ruiz.es:4040 it says:

> Parse Dashboard can only be remotely accessed via HTTPS

so these are my solutions:

1.- According to Parse (https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-dashboard)

> Deploying in production
>
> If you're deploying to a provider like Heroku, or Google App Engine, the SSL endpoint is terminated early and handled by the provider and you may encounter this error: Parse Dashboard can only be remotely accessed via HTTPS.
>
> Before going further, make sure your server cannot be reachable via HTTP. See the provider documentation for force HTTPS connections to your deployment.
>
> Set the environment variable PARSE_DASHBOARD_ALLOW_INSECURE_HTTP=1 to tell parse server to skip the secure tests.

so I set my environment variable to 1. But nothing happend.

2.- I have ALREADY https enabled (try https://rafael-ruiz.es). But when I try: https://rafael-ruiz.es:4040 it doesn't work.

What's wrong with this?

Thanks.

---

QUESTION:

Can it be because I have to configure some ports with my SSL certificate?

Comment: Where did you set this variable "PARSE_DASHBOARD_ALLOW_INSECURE_HTTP=1"?

Comment: As Environment variable

Comment: Did you ever find the solution?

Comment: You should access http and not https if you've disabled SSL. Happy to try and help if you have further problems/still need this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For first way:
you can use "--allowInsecureHTTP true" parameter on command line and for authentication use users section of config file:

```
   {
      "apps": [...],
      "users": [
      {
           "user":"user1",
           "pass":"pass"
      },
      {
           "user":"user2",
           "pass":"pass"
      }
   ]
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

Follow these steps to get parse dashboard running and accessible over public ip:

1. Create a config file your-config-filename.json
2. Add the following json structure to it and don't forget to replace with your app values:

```js
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "serverURL": "https://api.parse.com/1",
      "appId": "myAppId",
      "masterKey": "myMasterKey",
      "javascriptKey": "myJavascriptKey",
      "restKey": "myRestKey",
      "appName": "My Parse.Com App"
    },
    {
      "serverURL": "http://localhost:1337/parse",
      "appId": "myAppId",
      "masterKey": "myMasterKey",
      "appName": "My Parse Server App"
    }
  ],
"users": [
    {
      "user":"user1",
      "pass":"pass"
    },
    {
      "user":"user2",
      "pass":"pass"
    }
  ]
}
```

3. Save the config file and run the following command:

```js
parse-dashboard --config <your-config-filename>.json --allowInsecureHTTP true
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

The change is

app.use('/parse-dashboard', new ParseDashboard(config.dashboard, { allowInsecureHTTP: true }));

instead of

app.use('/parse-dashboard', ParseDashboard(config.dashboard, true));

you will find this code in index.js